# Deleted account from Stack Overflow still accessible on Meta

Tags: support, login, deleted-accounts

I have created one account (another) on Stack Overflow and was able to login with Meta Stack Exchange without joining this community. Then I have deleted that account from Stack Overflow, and I suppose to be not logged in in any community, however, my meta account is still accessible!

I'm wondering if there is no way to delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange are separate sites, and while your accounts are *linked* to each other, they can live without each other. So you'll have to delete your account here as well. This is unlike Meta Stack *Overflow*; that account has been deleted with the main account.

There's no way to delete all accounts at once, see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/295232).